# Automatic conversion from int to string in PHP

Tags: php, string, function, integer

In PHP, I have a variable of the type Integer.
When I pass it to a function, it's converted to a string.
I tested it with var_dump. It's an integer when I call the function.
Directly after the function call, it's a string.

Code:

```
public function setId($id)
{
    var_dump($id);
    // call of method "checkIfInteger" --> is_int($arg)
}
```

EDIT: Ok guys, I got it. In my setId method, I had another check method that trimmed the parameter (&$id) - when I enter '   10     ' for example, I worked with a (trimmed) string afterwards.

Another question:
I use intval, but intval('OK') returns an integer.
'25' should return true, 25 too, 2.5 should return false, and 'ok' too.
Is there a function available?

Comment: okay, and what's the problem?

Comment: can you explain why this happens?

Comment: depends on the code around it, which you haven't shown. I just tried `$t = 10; var_dump($t); function test($t) { var_dump($t); } test($t);` and both state int(10), so as base code, there is no casting.

Comment: I tried the same and the `var_dump($id)` inside the function is still an integer for me.

Comment: I want to be sure that it's no double, so I don't wanna use is_numeric.

Comment: @DachBoden the code you show does not result in the conversion you show, so you're going to have to show how you use this code to effect a different variable type. As plain PHP, that function plus a call with a number does not lead to an implicit type conversion

Answer (score 0):

A variable is not converted to a string. Quick check:

```
<?php

function setId($id)
{
    var_dump($id);
    // call of method "checkIfInteger" --> is_int($arg)
}

$a = 1;

setId($a);
```

Result is: int(1)

Where is your $id comming from? How do you know that it's an int before the method call?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Where ever you wanted an integer, why not try this.?
int $id = intval($id, 0);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

### That depends on how you send the parameter to your function...

Seems like you sent the param like this...

```
setId("1");// which will be a string ofcourse...
```

Try sending as `setId(1);`  you will get integer in your `var_dump` output.

**EDIT :**

```
<?php
$id=1;
if(gettype($id)=="integer")
{
    setId($id);
}
else
{
    echo "Function will not be called because ID is not an integer!";
}

function setId($id)
{
    var_dump($id);
}
```

Comment: Maybe that's possible. The parameter that I pass to the function could be a string. I just need a way to make sure that my parameter contains a integer value.

Comment: @DachBoden, You can make use of `gettype` for that. See the edited answer. Try playing around with `$id="1";` , the function will not be called.